# Allow room owners to find a desired trash room by ID

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools

Currently, the only way to search for a room to move messages to is by name. This is great if your room's preferred trash room has a consistent name, [but occasionally people like to be hilarious](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29125691#29125691).

That's all well and good, and was a good joke at the time, but when I wanted to move some spam questions out later, it was impossible to search for. If I could just type '165' and find Android Hell, regardless of what name it's currently going by, I'd be able to clear trash without having to rename the room to something searchable all the time.